# Is there some libraries to solve SBR for akka-cluster except the commercial solution

Tags: akka

We are using akka-cluster/akka-sharding for the business logic. In the cluster, it may encounter the split brain problem. I know lightbend has the solution, but it is charged.

Is there some libraries to solve SBR for akka-cluster except the commercial solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a try for

https://github.com/TanUkkii007/akka-cluster-custom-downing

```
"com.github.TanUkkii007" %% "akka-cluster-custom-downing" % "0.0.13"



//akka.cluster.downing-provider-class = "tanukki.akka.cluster.autodown.MajorityLeaderAutoDowning"

custom-downing {
  stable-after = 5s

  majority-leader-auto-downing {
    majority-member-role = ""
    down-if-in-minority = true
    shutdown-actor-system-on-resolution = true
  }
}
```